# How to add a validation function to joi.any()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

How can I extend `joi.any()` to add a new rule to it? So that I can use that rule on any existing type, like `joi.boolean()` or `joi.string()` for example.

I know how to extend joi with an extension to add a new custom type, but doing it that way I can't combine the new type with existing types.

I'd like to be able to do `joi.boolean().myrule()` and `joi.string().myrule()` and for any other existing types. How can I do it? I'm using it with the latest version of joi if it makes a difference.

Is there some way to do `joi.any.extend()` to add new rules to `any()` instead of `joi.extend()` (which adds a new type).

Answer (score 0):

I saw the code and I don't think that is possible(correct me if I am wrong). The closest you can do is this:
https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/test/extend.js#L95

```
const custom = Joi.extend({
  type: /^s/, // <<< regex for type
  rules: {
    hello: {
      validate(value, helpers, args, options) {
        return 'hello';
      },
    },
  },
});

const string = custom.string().hello();
expect(string.type).to.equal('string');
expect(string.hello().validate('goodbye').value).to.equal('hello');

const symbol = custom.symbol().hello();
expect(symbol.type).to.equal('symbol');
expect(symbol.hello().validate(Symbol('x')).value).to.equal('hello');
```

Because in the https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/lib/index.js#263:

```
for (const type of joi._types) {
    if (extension.type.test(type)) {
        const item = Object.assign({}, extension);
        item.type = type;
        item.base = joi[type]();
        extended.push(item);
    }
}
```

Joi is checking all the types that it has with the `type` regex.

Maybe you can make a customType with a regex that matches the types that you want to match(or all types). Then instead of, for example, `Joi.string()` you can use `custom.string()`.